# Nested Array Visitor ANTLR4

Tags: python-3.x, antlr4, nested-lists

I already make parser rules for nested array, something like  " '[' expr(',' expr)* ']' #ArrayExpr ". So, I can already define a nested array like arr = [1,2,[1,[2]]]. What I don't understand is, how make visitor function in python to call nested array, maybe like arr[2][0] should have value 1 or arr[2][1] should have value [2]?

This is what I did for non nested array. (I already have a dictionary named vars in visitor class)

```
def visitIndexExpr(self, ctx):
        return self.vars.get(ctx.var.text, 0.0)[int(self.visit(ctx.expr()))]
```

I can solve the case non nested array by making a dictionary in visitor class, but the nested one is still a mystery to me. I want some function like that for nested array. Can we do the same thing for nested array? if so, how? Thank you.

Comment: @BartKiers No, my grammar cant do nested array, just non nested array. How to make grammar for nested array? And what the visitor function like the above would you make?

Comment: @BartKiers  Yes I can already define it using the above grammar, but just assume you want to construct it from the beginning, what will you do? (both in grammar and visitor)